Meaning of a sign composed of forward slashes with dots
Can someone tell me what the sign (in the middle of the pic) means. The sign with 2 forward slashes and 4 dots.


I’m pretty sure that symbol means some kind of repeat (which is why I’ve added that tag), but I’m not sure what it’s doing above a barline.

Context helps.  Please provide a picture of the whole piece or at least tell us which hymnal it is from so we can look it up.

The sign is most likely an indication that the line of words is to be repeated.
The sign itself appears to be a variation on the simile sign shown on Wikipedia. There are two indications that it refers to the words. Firstly it is placed in the space between staves where words are often located (even though the words in this case are elsewhere on the page), and secondly there is no gap left in the music where a repetition of music could be inserted.
In the 1929 edition of The Scottish Psalter and Church Hymnary this tune (Regent Square) is used for the hymn Glory be to God the Father, and the fifth line "Glory, glory" needs to be sung twice.
In newer hymn books such as Together in Song (1999) the words of the fifth line are written as "Glory, glory, glory, glory", so the sign is redundant, but it is still present. It is even present when the tune is used for a different hymn, where the words are not exactly repeated.

The two most common texts for this tune are Christ is Made the Sure Foundation and Angels From the Realms of Glory.  In the second case, the two bars shown in the image are the first two bars of the refrain: Come and worship, / Come and worship, / Worship Christ, the newborn King.  (The other hymn does not have a refrain.)  In the absence of an explicit explanation, and especially given the form of the sign in question, this is definitely the most plausible explanation.  I'll delete my answer.

There are no lyrics in the OP's score. What range exactly should be repeated? The two measures connected by the symbol, right?

@user1079505 it's a hymn.  The text will normally be printed somewhere else on the page.  The words "come and worship" are repeated.

@phoog so which notes or measures should be repeated?

@user1079505 none.  The text is repeated with the different notes.  This notation is common in manuscripts, though more commonly with a single slash and perhaps single dots or sometimes with ij.

@user1079505i had another look at the other hymnal where I saw this tune with the same notation.  There the tune is given for the hymn "Look, ye saints; the sight is glorious", which is 8.7.8.7.4.7, so to fit the four-syllable line of text to the eight syllable musical phrase, the four syllables are repeated, hence the symbol.

@user1079505 in following the comment thread, I had lost sight of this from the answer: "in the 1929 edition of The Scottish Psalter and Church Hymnary this tune (Regent Square) is used for the hymn Glory be to God the Father, and the fifth line "Glory, glory" needs to be sung twice."  So: the text is presented elsewhere on the page in verse form, the next to last line comprises the two words "glory, glory," and the first two measures at the bottom of the page are to be sung "glory, glory, glory, glory." See p. 11 of a different edition: https://archive.org/details/churchhymnaryau00staigoog/
